# The Starting Point

Tags: steganography, anagram, movies

```
This is just the start of the program. What we start never goes unfinished.
```

The signal went dead.

Our assets have been located successfully, there was one step left.

I managed to crack three firewalls so far, but these days many have realized you can never have too much security. Another guarded gateway was waiting for me. Hopefully this will be the last.

The transmitter clicked on again.

```
The hash key appears to be a film. You may appreciate this intelligence.

-FORWARDED MESSAGE-

*Notice tip

Directed by 
ClashRhinoPro10

Produced by 
SameMom@H

Starring
CoolAIPondRaider
TakeWanBean
Trolli&MicroA
NepalGlee
HAMtoDRY
And many more

*Could also be be Topic 9. Maybe it's a nice tip, no? 

-END MESSAGE-
```

*You've got to be kidding me,* I thought to myself. I swear ClashRhinoPro10 is a 12 year old Minecraft Youtuber. *CoolAIPondRaider?* more like *DumbKidCringeyNoob!* I don't care as long as it helps me get into this thing, but I need to punch the dude who designed this later. Punch him real hard.

Enough of that, I gotta work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's more to it than this, but

> the film is clearly INCEPTION (which is *almost* an anagram of NOTICE TIP and *is* an anagram of TOPIC NINE and NICE TIP NO), directed by CHRISTOPHER NOLAN (anagram of CLASH RHINO PRO TEN), produced by EMMA THOMAS (anagram of SAME MOM AT H), starring LEONARDO DI CAPRIO (anagram of COOL AI POND RAIDER), etc.

And of course

> INCEPTION is a rough synonym for "starting point", hence the title.

I think

> the not-quite-anagram-ness of NOTICE TIP is simply an error. At any rate, the other anagrams I checked *do* match up properly so e.g. it isn't the case that there's a wrong letter in each one that we need to put together.

Comment: "Notice Tip" is not an anagram of "Inception". "Inception" only has one "t".

Comment: Oh, so it isn't. So either OP has erred or there's another level here.

Comment: I've had errors in my past 4 puzzles, but somehow they go unnoticed. Either I'm really bad at making these things, or my proofreading skills suck. There's 2 more puzzles that I am planning, but I'm no longer confident in myself...